# Time evolution of a wave function

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to solve Time Dependent Schroedinger Equation using Operator Splitting Method.
The formula for time evolution is as follows:
`U[t+dt]=Exp[-I V dt] Exp[-I K dt] U[dt]`,where `K` is the kinetic energy in momentum space and `V` is the potential energy in real space.Since both `K`and `V` are in different space, Fast Fourier Transform and Inverse Fast Fourier Transform is Used. Here `U[dt]` is in real space.
and the formula looks like
`U[t+dt]=Exp[- I V dt] InverseFourier[Exp[-I K dt] Fourier[U[dt]]`
Therefore, U[dt] is calculated at later times in real space. The Mathematica code for this method is

```
{nmax = 2^7, L = 20.0, dz = L/nmax, dkz = N[2 \[Pi]/L], kzmax = N[\[Pi]/dz]};
zGrid = Table[-L/2 + (n - 1) dz, {n, 1, nmax}];
kzGrid = Table[-kzmax + (q - 1) dkz, {q, 1, nmax}];
kzpGrid = kzGrid // RotateLeft[#, nmax/2] &;
Vmodel[z_] = VHO[z] E^(-b z^2);
b = 0.1;
VHO[z_] = Vo + (z^2)/2;
Vo = -2.0;
V = Vmodel[zGrid];
K = (kzpGrid^2)/2;
{ntmax = 2000, T = 10.0, dt = T/ntmax};
U[dt_]@psi_ := UV[dt] InverseFourier[UK[dt] Fourier[psi]];
UV[dt] = E^(-I V dt);
UK[dt] = E^(-I K dt);
psi[nt_, psi0_] := Nest[U[dt][#] &, psi0, nt];
psi0[0] = Exp[I kPo z] Exp[-wPo (z^2)/2] (wPo/\[Pi])^(1/4) /. {kPo -> 1.0, wPo -> 2.0 } /. z -> zGrid//N;
Do[psi0[nt] = psi[nt, psi0[nt - 10]], {nt, 10, ntmax, 10}];
```

Every looks fine to me but the Do Loop in the last line is not getting executed.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It completes on my machine. What output do you expect? `psi0[10]` through `psi0[2000]` in steps of 10 are all defined.

Comment: Yaa I expect psi0[10] until psi[2000] in steps of 10. In my Machine Execution stops at Do Loop

Comment: Then it works... what is the problem here exactly?

Comment: The do loop is not executing in my machine

Comment: Did you try ```Remove["Global`*"]```, then running it? What version are you on? It works on 12.1.1.

Comment: Yes I tried Remove["Global`*"] still not working, Am using 12.0

Comment: I am running Mathematica 12.0.0.0, and your code appears to work fine for me as well. Have you tried restarting the Kernel/Mathematica?

Comment: Yes. I have restarted Kernel several times. Can you please share, what output you are getting?

Comment: `Do` does not produce an output. After executing the `Do` you need to look at some or all of `psi0` to see what the `Do` did.

Comment: Thank you all so much, I figured out my mistake.